# Copying live site that is using older version of WP to localhost

Tags: 404-error, localhost

I'm trying to make a copy of my live site that is running an old version of Wordpress to my local server, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I followed [this](http://www.webnots.com/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-localhost/) tutorial, but when I go to http://localhost/wordpress I get a 404 error saying, "The requested URL /wordpress/ was not found on this server." Could someone help me out please?

Comment: this is a permission or web server configuration problem that is not related to WP. are you sure you have php installed and configured?

Comment: @MarkKaplun yeah, I installed everything to MAMP/htdocs directory

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I do when I copy a Wordpress site (old/new version, live or local).

1. Download all the wp-content/ directory and replace the files (nothing else)
2. Rename the wp-config-sample.php in wp-config.php and adapt the environments variables to your new environment (database name, database user, database password...)
3. Download the database's content as a .sql file and import it in your new environment

   4. Run this SQL commands in your new database to update ALL the urls (site, posts, attachements...) : https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/

That should work fine once all these steps done.

Comment: So should I download the version the website is using, and replace the wp-content directory in that wordpress installation with the live website's wp-content directory?

Comment: yup if you want a copy, that's an important step.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress settings, there are 2 locations to enter the WP site's URL. (See screenshot.) These are also stored in the wp_options table of the wordpress database. If they do not match the URL of your new server (in your case, 'localhost'), then you will get an error like this.
[image]
If you can't access the settings page (because wordpress won't load), then you'll have to edit the first two fields of the wp_options table.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't access anything when I went to the URL. I ran a SQL query to change the old URLs to the new one but it didn't work either.

Comment: What is your environment? For my localhost, I use MAMP, so I have to make sure the preferences point to the 'wordpress' folder. Otherwise, I get the 404 error.

Comment: Yeah I use MAMP as well. Not sure what you mean by the preferences pointing to the wordpress folder, but my document root is htdocs, which the wordpress folder was in.